# Не могу удалить COOKIE

Tags: php, cookie

Такая проблема, установил COOKIE и не могу теперь удалить.
Устанавливал так.

```
$loginRemember = [
    "uid" => $user_info["id"],
    "upas" => $login["password"]
];

setcookie('LOGIN_REMEMBER', json_encode($loginRemember), time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/', 'mysite.com');
```

После установки, на другой странице сайта делал для теста так

```
unset($_COOKIE['LOGIN_REMEMBER']);
setcookie('LOGIN_REMEMBER', null, time()-3600 );
```

затем проверяю.

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Вижу а она все равно есть. Что делаю не так?

Comment: То есть вы прямо в куках храните пароль открытым текстом? Определённо плохая идея

Comment: Ну и конечно сразу же смущает, что у вас в этих двух setcookie разное количество параметров, что естественно приведёт к разному поведению